# flutter firestore, add new object in array

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I have array of objects, I want to add new object when user enter new data in the array?

```
Firestore.instance.collection(city).document('Attractions').updateData(
                        "data", FieldValue.arrayUnion(obj)
                      );
```

This shows error, How can I achieve this with flutter?

Comment: Edit your Question with updated code & new Error

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Right Format is :

```
Firestore.instance.collection(city).document('Attractions').updateData({"data": FieldValue.arrayUnion(obj)});
```

`updateData` Take `Map<String,dynamic>` as data.

In your Code you are having `,` as separator between key - value instead it should be `:`

Comment: Thanks for you help, I tried it, But now I am getting error:

Comment: The error states:
The argument type 'Map<String, dynamic>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'

Comment: You need to add more Code for me to debug. Plus the new error could be of some other area of code also.

Comment: FieldValue.arrayUnion takes in a list. Use this and it should fix your error - Firestore.instance.collection(city).document('Attractions').updateData({"data": FieldValue.arrayUnion([obj])});

Answer (score 17):

@anmol.majhail 's is right, but to solve @Sami Ullah's problem, you must first make a list and add the object into the list like this:

```
var list = [objectBeingAdded];
Firestore.instance.collection('city').document('Attractions').updateData({"data": FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)});
```

Comment: where are you using 'list' objects while updating your data in firestore?

Comment: He meant to use it instead of 'obj' in FieldValue.arrayUnion(obj). Easier way is just to do FieldValue.arrayUnion([obj]).

Comment: @AlexHartford I know, I just thought that it would be easier to understand and notice if I made it two statements instead of one

Comment: You still need to correct obj -> list with your current answer.

Comment: wrapping obj with [] did it for me.  thanks.

Answer (score 7):

#### Null safe code:

Say this is the data you want to add

```dart
Map<String, dynamic> someData = {
  'foo': 1,
  'bar': true,
};
```

- **Add the data with unique auto-generated ID:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .add(someData) 
      .then((_) => print('Added'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Add failed: $error'));
  ```
- **Add the data with your own ID:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('document_id') // <-- Document ID
      .set(someData) 
      .then((_) => print('Added'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Add failed: $error'));
  ```
- **Add the object to an array:**

  ```dart
  var collection = FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('collection');
  collection 
      .doc('document_id') // <-- Document ID
      .set({'data': FieldValue.arrayUnion(list)}) // <-- Add data
      .then((_) => print('Added'))
      .catchError((error) => print('Add failed: $error'));
  ```

Answer (score 4):

### 2023 Updated Syntax:

[From the Fireabse docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#dart_12)

```dart
final washingtonRef = db.collection("cities").doc("DC");

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
  "regions": FieldValue.arrayUnion(["greater_virginia"]),
});

// Atomically remove a region from the "regions" array field.
washingtonRef.update({
  "regions": FieldValue.arrayRemove(["east_coast"]),
});
```

Answer (score 2):

This is a working function I built that adds new Maps to an array in my Firestore Services class. I'm using Json Serializable to annotate all my model classes.  userTemplateSections is a data field in my userTemplate firestore documents. I take userTemplate as a constructor of the 'addUserTemplateSection' function to make sure I'm editing the correct document.

I also added the function I made to delete Maps from a firestore document array.

'''

```
Future<void> addUserTemplateSection(
      {UserTemplate userTemplate, String title, String summary}) async {
    try {
      final UserTemplateSection userTemplateSection =
          UserTemplateSection(title: title, summary: summary);
      await _firestore
          .document(FirestorePath.userTemplate(uid, userTemplate.id))
          .updateData(
        {
          'userTemplateSections':
              FieldValue.arrayUnion([userTemplateSection.toJson()])
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

'''

'''

```
Future<void> deleteUserTemplateSection({
    UserTemplate userTemplate,
    UserTemplateSection userTemplateSection,
  }) async {
    try {
      await _firestore
          .document(FirestorePath.userTemplate(uid, userTemplate.id))
          .updateData(
        {
          'userTemplateSections':
              FieldValue.arrayRemove([userTemplateSection.toJson()])
        },
      );
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }
```

'''